# Polymer 1.0 not working

Tags: polymer, bower, polymer-1.0

I am trying to make a simple 'Hello World!' element. I have tried installing the polymer components with bower and I have used the zip file. I have also use python and npm HTTP server but still I don't get any output. 

    `<html>
    <head>
    <title>Polymer</title>
    <script src="bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="import" href="elements/hello-world.html">
    </head>
    <body unresolved>
    <hello-world></hello-world>
    </body>
    </html>`

with the element file

    `<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-mini.html">
    <polymer-element name="hello-world" noscript>
    <template>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </template>
    </polymer-element>`

Comment: `<polymer-element>` is Polymer 0.5. You want `<dom-module>`. See https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/start/quick-tour.html.

Answer (score 7):

You are using the wrong API for the polymer-element. You should be using the `<dom-module>` like Trevor Dixon mentioned.

[See Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/wXph35juOG3f01JzrIjm?p=preview)

```
<link rel="import" href="../bower_components/polymer/polymer-mini.html">

<dom-module id="hello-world">
    <template>
    <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
Polymer({
  is: 'hello-world'
})
</script>
```